# Join string in a LINQ Lambda query

Tags: linq, lambda

Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

LINQ will not allow me to use Aggregate() and string.Join(), since it cannot translate it to SQL.

I could also not find a relevant function in the DBFunctions class.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps you could state more clearly what "how" is? You can use string concatenation (e.g. operator `+`) in LINQ to SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely certain what you're asking... Would this solve your problem?

```
var strings = new List<List<string>>() {
    new List<string> {"abc","cde"},
    new List<string> {"123","456"}
};

var joinedString = strings.Select(s => string.Join(",", s));
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately .NET functions like String.Join() cannot be directly translated into SQL. Because of this, you can't use them how you would like. You are on the right track mentioning the `DBFunctions` class. This class contains functions that *can* be used in linq to SQL queries.

The correct way to achieve what you want is to write a linq query that contains the collection of items that you want to join and materialize them first. After that, you can perform any .NET functions on the data.

```
var notes = await Entities.Select(x => new
{
    x.Id,                                  // int
    Notes = x.Notes.Select(a => a.Comment) // IEnumerable<string>
})
.Where(x => x.Notes.Contains("your filter string")) // filtering
.Skip(1)
.Take(10)
.ToArrayAsync(); // and finally you materialize the data

// Now that the data has been materialized, you can perform .NET functions with String.Join
var joinedNotes = notes.Select(x => new
{
    x.Id,
    ConcatenatedNotes = String.Join(", ", x.Notes)
});
```

Comment: well the problem is I am building a queryable and want to materialize the data later (also contains preserving and skip/take). I however also use expressions based one propertynames to filter data. One of the properties is a list of strings. I wanted to concat the strings and then perform a contains on the concatenated string

Comment: @Kai please see my updated answer that shows a more complex example. I think it should answer your question now.